# Disable Grails plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

In my Grails app, I want to prevent the Searchable plugin from loading when running my unit tests. I tried doing this using the following code in the Bootstrap class

```
def grailsApplication

def init = {servletContext ->
    def currentEnv = grails.util.Environment.current.name

    if (currentEnv == 'test') {

        def doNothing = {println "Searchable is disabled"}

        // This returns null!
        def searchablePluginClass = grailsApplication.getClassForName("SearchableGrailsPlugin")

        searchablePluginClass.metaClass.doWithDynamicMethods = doNothing 
        searchablePluginClass.metaClass.doWithSpring = doNothing 
        searchablePluginClass.metaClass.doWithApplicationContext = doNothing 
    }
}
```

However this doesn't work because `grailsApplication.getClassForName("SearchableGrailsPlugin")` returns null, presumably because this class isn't on the classpath when this code runs. Is there any other way that I can disable this plugin?

Answer (score 9):

I found a solution. Add the following to Config.groovy:

```
environments {
    test {
        plugin {
            excludes = "searchable"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure how to disable the plugin, there might be a way with [native compass XML](http://www.opensymphony.com/compass/versions/1.1/html/core-configuration.html)

With grails you might be able to make unit testing more bearable with the following...
Install this additional plugin:
     grails install-searchable-config

This will give you a grails-app/conf/Searchable.groovy file. You can edit
     environments.test.searchable closure to at least disable bulkIndexOnStartup and mirrorChanges.

```
 environments {
 test {
    searchable {
        // disable bulk index on startup
        bulkIndexOnStartup = false
        mirrorChanges = false

        // use faster in-memory index
        compassConnection = "ram://test-index"
    }
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable a plugin for the test build, which running tests uses - the following is possible in the BuildConfig.groovy if you include your plugin there;

```
environments {
            development {
                compile ":searchable:0.6.6"
            }
            test {
            }
            production {
                compile ":searchable:0.6.6"
            }
        }
}
```

This stops the build environment from including the plugin when testing, however, this WILL also effect a test release if you use this environment to build UAT releases.